# Help Needed in web view

Tags: iphone

HI All,

I am using web view to open a web page in my iphone app, its woking well, and able to connect to the mentioned web page, but in the web page view it shows crossed images instead of the actual images there, and look is also not so good, is there any way to rectify this.

With Thanks
iPhoneDeveloper11

Comment: Furthermore, does the webpage work correctly on other platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's many ways to improve the view of your web page. This is basically how I'm doing this:

1. First you need to download the webpage. I use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) for this purpose.
2. Analyze the response you receive. Print a string from the response:

   NSString * response = [request responseString];

   NSLog(@"HTML code: %@", response);
3. Scan and replace the html code by use of [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Example code:

   - [Parsing CSV Data](http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data)
   - [Writing a parser using NSScanner](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.html)

The crossed image could be an image tag which does not contain a valid url.
You can use NSScanner to find the image tag and correct the url, or if you want to you can resize or align the image. Learn about simple image tags on this link: [Simple Image HTML Tags.](http://www.goldcoastwebdesigns.com/12.shtml)